# handling of column exist without exception

Tags: java, oracle

I would like to put up this question for a scenario i have come across.

We have read-only user who can access all the schema on database say 'X'. X is having different users on this say "Person1","Person2". Person1 has a table Name with cols(First_Name,Last_Name). Person2 has same table but only has First_Name column.

I'm trying to check always with select Last_NAME from &schema&.Name where 1=0;  for existence of the column for further processing. This will always give an exception for Person2.Name . Will this cause any perf issue in any case my first question ?
Second,Can we handle this without exception . 
Does oracle provide any such tables like user_tab_columns this only give the tables for the current user in my case it will be the read only user so i'm not getting the even this user has access to all the schema

Comment: Have you tried all_tab_columns ? you can filter by the owner, table_name, column_name

Comment: Thanks Maxim for your quick response. I did not try that. Look like it gives me columns by owner. Do you suggest this from performance perspective ?

Comment: Should be quite fast if you specify all of three - owner, table_name, column_name.

Comment: The `all_` views are typically slower than the corresponding `user_` and `dba_` views as they have more possible permissions to check. From a performance perspective it would probably be quickest just to issue the query optimistically and deal with any exceptions. It seems a rather odd system though, if you don't know what columns you have to query.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation William.  Agree the system seems to be odd, but just needed to know if we can have any graceful handling of such scenario. This helps a lot.   Thanks again !